# range of transmission line?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-engineering

I am not electrical engineer by profession. So, accept my apology if my question sounds stupid. I am simulating a situation on computer where electric power is being send from one point to another through transmission lines (500kv). The total length of transmission line is 1600 km. Could any one help me after how many kilometres typically a step-up transformer is used to boost up the power? Also what is the total fraction (approximately) of power being lost during this process?

Comment: We don't know the size of the transmission lines. Thicker wires have a lower resistance than thinner wires.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for both types of wires, after how many kilometres do we need the step up transformer?

Comment: people have written books to answer this question. namely isbn 0071771921. study pi model for transmission lines

Comment: Traditional power transmission doesn't run power this great a distance. 1600 km ~ 1000 miles, or the distance from Florida to Chicago. Standard practice is to have power stations much closer to the load than that, though with distant wind farms, that practice may have had to change somewhat. Regardless, any power lost in the transmission lines doesn't generate revenue, so designers would balance ongoing revenue losses against the cost of reducing those losses.

The book that @hassan789 suggested looks like a very good and thorough reference work.

Comment: The model of a power line is also affected by number of conductors, and the spacing between them. You won't necessarily find a transformer just up in a major intercity power line either - the lines will go through a switch yard, where they can be sat on a concrete pad and interfaced with distribution to provide service to customers. Transmission grade transformers are typically rated for wildly high voltages at hundreds of amps - meaning they get very, very big, and fenced in. For fun you should google a regional transmission map like ERCOT or SPP.

Comment: Never heard of booster transformers for voltages above 10kV.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity of Electro Magnetic waves in a Transmission Line is slightly less than the velocity of light --i.e. 300,000 Km.For a 60Hz system ,one wavelength will be 5000 Km.A quarter wavelength will be 1250 Km.A Transmission Line of this length will behave like a Quarter wave Antenna and radiate a lot of power to space by  **radiation** . 
 For transmitting Power over **800 Km** ,High Voltage Dc Transmission (**HVDC**) is therefore preferred. 
 However , if an AC line needs to be connected in parallel to an HVDC Line , then Flexible AC Transmission System (**FACTS**) is used.
 You can get some more details from the *internet* by searcching for HVDC Transmssion and Facts Transmission. 
 Also you may look into the brochures of Power Companies like ABB,SIEMENS, GE etc.